# TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function

Tags: discord.js

**Code**:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix2}red`)){
    if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Red')) return message.channel.send(`You already have the role!`)
    let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Red");(r => r.name === "Red");
    let member = message.member;
    message.delete(1)
    member.addRole(role).catch(console.error)
    }   
})
```

I am trying to make a command that will give the user that role.
**Error**:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Red");
                                       ^

TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function
```

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you on?

Comment: newest one i think

Comment: Yea then it's message.guild.roles.find

Comment: Though I dont recommend v12, they just made all syntaxes more complicated, there's no improvement to v11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `message.guild.roles.cache.find`.

Comment: like that `let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Red");(r => r.name === "Red");`

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the condition twice.

Comment: i changed `let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "red"); to let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Red");` and i am getting `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object`